# Prevent page interaction while modal is open

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

This seems like a simple question that I'm sure I've seen done, but cannot find the answer.

I want to basically disable the page behind a bootstrap modal when it's displaying. In my example, I'm displaying a modal when I try to navigate past the top/bottom of a table, warning the user about it. But, if they, before dismissing it, do it again, I get a second modal stacked on top of the first, and now they have to close two windows... etc, etc, etc...

How do I prevent that?

Comment: Bootstrap by default will not allow either of the things you describe.  [From the docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/components/modal/) (v5, you didn't mention which version, but they all prohibit what you describe): "*Clicking on the modal “backdrop” will automatically close the modal*", and "*Bootstrap only supports one modal window at a time. Nested modals aren’t supported as we believe them to be poor user experiences.*" Edit your question, add a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Yea, BS doesn't seem to provide what I needed. I ended up rolling my own solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about your bootstrap version and current scenario. I think you should provide your current code to know what you really mean.

But seems you need to use the backdrop="static" attribute to avoid that behaviour.

Using Twitter Bootstrap 3.x and 4.x you should add this attribute to your modal element: (https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/components/modal/#static-backdrop)

```
data-backdrop="static"
```

Using 5.x use this other one: (https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/modal/#static-backdrop)

```
data-bs-backdrop="static"
```